# download file with PAMIE

Tags: python, internet-explorer, pamie

I want to use [PAMIE](http://pamie.sourceforge.net/) to download a file. However, IE brings up that annoying "blocked this website from downloading" warning. Is there any way to automate bypassing that?

I want to do it this way because I need a programmatic way of browsing that retains cookies and stuff. If there is another way to do that, that could work as well. But I know doing it through PAMIE will definitely work, as it's just using IE, which works.

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883255. As far as I know, it still works. You could add your site to the Trusted Sites zone and disable the download prompt for that zone.

Comment: is there any way to do that automatically? through PAMIE maybe? i don't want to have to do that on dozens of computers manually

Comment: You could probably poke around in the registry and see what's being done when you modify the security zone settings, then provide a `.reg` file that users could double-click to import it, or use Python's `winreg` module to set them.